# cvs status - show full path

Tags: cvs, status

I want to use cvs status to show files that are modified/notUpToDate with the following command:

```
iuk323@rzhe168:/sm-work/iuk323/nz> cvs -q status | grep File | grep 'Locally\|Patch\|Merge'
File: makefile          Status: Locally Modified
File: scanreader.c      Status: Locally Modified
File: iftypes.h         Status: Locally Modified
File: build.xml         Status: Locally Modified
```

It is working like I would expect, but for example the makefile could be in numerous directorys. Is there a way to show the full path of the files ?

Solution (I found this in an other article):

```
cvs -q status|awk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=1 a=9 s='(Locally Modified)|(Needs Patch)|(Needs Checkout)|(Locally Modified)'
```

It shows the files that are not up to date. Under Repository revision one can find the full path.